# Using Jersey and JSON, how to ignore the root element?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, restkit

I'm using RestKit on the iOS side, and Jersey on the Java side to talk JSON.

RestKit is sending the following:

```
{
    "user": {
        "emailAddress": "someuser",
        "password": "somepassword"
    }
}
```

On the Java side, the User class is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    public String emailAddress;
    public String password;
    public List<UserForm> userForms;

    ... getters and setters ...
```

I have the following on the Jersey service:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public User login(User someUser) throws IOException 
{
 ...
```

Everything in the `someUser` object is null. So, I think I'm trying to get Jersey to forget the root node, because when he sends something back, it's in the form of:

```
{
    "emailAddress": "server",
    "password": "serverpass",
}
```

If it's of any help, my web.xml contains the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.something.services;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Sorry, I'm a bit new to Jersey, and I've been diggin' around like crazy to find the answer, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, y'all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want RestKit to remove the `user` key from the JSON (or rather to not add it), set the `rootKeyPath` on your request descriptor to `nil`.

Comment: Simple enough. Still would be curious how to do this on the Jersey side, that is, to ignore the root path.